# The right way to download images using selenium

Tags: selenium

I have read some articles that mentioned how to get image by `selenium`. For example:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    import requests
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http/https://your website")
    img=driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath leading to your element")#locating element
    src=img.get_attribute('src')#fetch the location of image
    img=requests.get(src)#fetch image
    with open('image.jpg','wb') as writer:#open for writing in binary mode
        writer.write(img.content)#write the image
```

But does this methods have a risk of more bandwidth cost?

Is there any way just like I right click on the image and `save as` it to local PC?

I have tried use javascript to do that:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById('someImageId');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
var theData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

and meet `cross-origin` problem

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
    at <anonymous>:5:23
```

It's workaround is make another request just like what I do not want in the first line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you know the URIs, then bypass `selenium` and use just `requests`.

Comment: @orde, the problem is I have to get URIs by `selenium` because the URIs are generated by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid increasing network footprint you can consider the following approach:

1. Take the screenshot of the entire page using i.e. [`get_screenshot_as_png` function](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L1099)
2. Get required element [`location`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L562) and [`size`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L545)
3. Extract "interesting" part of the page by cutting anything else but the required element's coordinates
4. Save the resulting file

Example code which stores the logo from the https://experitest.com/ site to `logo.png` file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.0);')
driver.get("https://experitest.com/")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='navbar-brand']/img")
location = element.location
size = element.size
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
im.save('logo.png')
driver.quit()
```

Assumptions:

- You have [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library installed (it should be as easy as `pip install pillow` command)
- Your OS [DPI scale level](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html) is set to 100%

Comment: Can I access image stored in `ChromeDriver`'s cache in `selenium`? Just like I do in regular Chrome Develop Tools.